# HTML Underline Email

Tags: html, email, outlook, signature, underline

I am trying to remove an underline for links for email signature however having difficulty. The issue is links are shown underline on mac outlook or from outlook to mac in general (tested on mac outlook and then tested on pc outlook to iphone).

A blue line appears with text-decoration as none, I have tried different ways such as having it in the style for href to having it in a span to the CSS multiple times, to using the method litmus suggests 'applelinks'.

Mac and PC show different results for me regarding this as one will show fine on one system but not the other such as a linkable href code will have an underline in apple products but look fine on pc, opposite is not having a href link and just having the link written out - this seems to appear fine on apple devices but blue and underlined on PC

I notice from inspecting the code it seems to be due to outlook adding a priority CSS of underline automatically - is there any way to overwrite this? as inline does not seem to work for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens when you try `text-decoration: none;` on anchor (perhaps with `!important;`)?

Comment: @Theraot It seems to ignore it and get rid of the text-decoration, a few attempts I made did make the text-decoration go to a span but still outlook was overriding it

Answer (score 0):

email clients adjust the HTML and CSS code by their own rules:

e.g.: gmail removes everything but the inner HTML of the body tag.

for most other clients you can have a style-tag in your header

```
<style type="text/css">
    a {text-decoration: none !important;}
</style>
```

**Don't use CSS comments as YAHOO!Mail might cause trouble.**

or

```
<a href="" style="text-decoration: none !important;">
    <span style="text-decoration: none !important;">
        text
    </span>
</a>
```

And follow these links to get more help

[campaignmonitor.com/css](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

[update-banning-blue-links-on-ios-devices](https://litmus.com/blog/update-banning-blue-links-on-ios-devices)

[email-clients/ios-blue-links](https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/ios-blue-links/)

Comment: Appreciated the response however this does not seem to work for me as on iPhone it still appears underlined even following the methods given especially the litmus one

Comment: ok sorry Dan,i haven't any iphone device,if i have i can check this problem,and dan if you really appreciate about my answer don't hesitate to mark it as useful. it's really help to me :)

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that first of Outlook simply refuses to keep any `style="text-decoration: none"` on `<a` tags.

adding a internal `<span` tag with the same works on most clients, but not safari/iOS.

To work around that use `style="display:inline-block"` to override the outer underline.